# Should handling cookies be a part of UI or Service layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, n-tier-architecture

Both UI and Service layers are exposed to network. Which one should cookie management be a part of?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies would come as part of your request which you can use and manage in your application at the backend or service layer. Only if there's a specific business requirement to maintain it on client side, you should go for it, probably javascript would help in that case.

Comment: Service layer is accessed by multiple clients like Android. Would it be right to leave a dependency of cookies there?

Comment: It doesn't feel wrong either, the only part which will matter is that you would be using the cookies for that particular session. You can write your custom logic to invalidate the cookies' objects once your job is done.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie management should be part of the Presentation Layer. The Service Layer contains the application logic and does not care how the application is presented.